# Using Eclipse 3.5 PDT, how do I stop it from automatically converting <? into <?php ?>?

Tags: php, eclipse, code-completion

I just upgraded to Eclipse 3.5 PDT, and everytime I type `<?`, it converts it into `<?php  ?>`. How do I turn that off?

Comment: Why do you want to turn it off?  Using the complete <?php instead of the short tag is generally accepted as better php structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to turn it off, it's under

Preferences -> PHP -> Editor -> Typing -> Close PHP Tag (?>)

It really is a best practice to use full `<?php` open tags however.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's best to use the full <?php tag, I just wanted to have the option to remove the auto-close.

Comment: AFAIK, the short tags are being deprecated in PHP 6

Comment: mainly because it conflicts with <?xml

Comment: @bucabay That never seemed to make sense to me: if in a XML context then don't use the short version.

Comment: Another dumb decision on the part of PHP if they remove short tag support for v6. Is `echo '<?xml...'` really that difficult?

Comment: Since 5.4 <?= $bla ?> is always enabled. IMHO this echo is better, and   since i don't write libraries other might use, and my servers have short_open_tags enabled. I don't see why not using the short echo